# Can js code on a site prevent other js code from detecting presence of flash?

Tags: javascript, flash, dom

I'm looking for a workaround to the "AdSense does not let you choose only images but no flash" issue. I'm rather a newbie to JS, but is there any way for one script to prevent other scripts embedded in a site from detecting the presence of the flash plugin? Even if it doesn't work with AdSense, it would be nice to know if there's a hack to do this that might work in other settings.

By the way, I suppose I wouldn't care if it failed to work on IE or obsolete browser versions.

Comment: If you are trying to defeat the AdSense detection of Flash, you're violating the AdSense Terms & Conditions. Eventually, Google may well notice and you'll find yourself barred from AdSense. For life. With a *completely* opaque, one-time-only appeals process that you're very unlikely to get a good result from. (Don't believe me? Have a read: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/AdSense/label?lid=215fb2e4b67e2667&hl=en) If you value your AdSense account (and whether you should is a matter for debate, it varies a *lot*), don't do it. Either work within the rules or use a different ad network.

Comment: I don't agree. -1 to TJ if I could. Basically, you're going to have to work with the existing code of AdSense. Have a look at it, as there is no universal way to disable detection of Flash.

Comment: @TJ: I don't see why Google should care if I want to exclude some ads from bidding. In principle I could do the same thing by turning on the review center and approving ads manually if and only if they're non-flash, with a huge amount of added work...

Comment: @Anonymous: Disagree if you want. If you muck about with the AdSense ads on your site, you're violating their T&Cs and they **do** periodically review sites (automatically and manually) and they just shut you out if they believe, at their sole discretion, you're in violation. They won't tell you why they've banned you, they won't tell you how they *think* you've violated the T&Cs, and your odds of getting the ban reversed are low.

Comment: @R..: All I can do is repeat my last sentence: If you value your AdSense account, don't muck about trying to trick AdSense. If you can take it or leave it (for life), go for it and have fun, just be ready to switch to another ad network if they notice. (And don't think being a small site -- if your site is small -- will protect you.)

Comment: @TJ: Thanks for your concern. I am presently only using text ads and merely *considering* something like this as an idea for future use, so I'm happy to hear a balanced set of opinions on whether it's a good idea as well as just how to do it. However, I reviewed the Terms and Conditions and could not find any language prohibiting doing something like this. The closest is a prohibition on modifying their JS, but Metal's solution (and my original idea) centers on modifying the environment, not their code. Is there a particular passage you can cite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like adsense detects flash by looking at the content of navigator.plugins["Shockwave Flash"]. Unfortunately, you can't just set just that to a different value, as browsers won't let you. Similarly, you can't set navigator.plugins. Some browsers let you delete navigator.plugins, but not all of them.

However, you can set navigator. So the path to do what you want involves creating a fake navigator object.

```
var real_navigator = navigator;
navigator = { plugins:[], mimeTypes:[] };
for (var k in real_navigator) {
  var t = typeof real_navigator[k];
  if (t == "string" || t == "function") {
    navigator[k] = real_navigator[k];
  }
}
```

At that point, you can still have scripts that inspect your user-agent and such, but plugins and mimetypes won't show up.

It's not fool-proof, and you'd have to stub ActiveXObject if you want IE to play along, but overall, this should get you closer to your goal.

Comment: Which browsers do let you delete navigator.plugins?

Comment: Google Chrome does. That's the only browser on my mac laptop that does though. Neither Firefox nor Safari does it.